# How get the correct date?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, react-calendar

I've got an issue in my react/next project, this is the function:

```
const handleDateChange = (date) => { 
    console.log(date); // Fri Mar 10 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit) (I get this date from react-calendar component) 

    setWeekDay(date.toISOString().slice(0, 10)); 
    setShowCalendar(!showCalendar);

    console.log(weekDay); // 2021-03-09 WHY? 
};
```

As you can see I get a String. I want to mutate the array into the format `yyyy-mm-dd`. This is working fine BUT if I choose, e.g. `10.0.2023`, in the calendar and the function is called it mutates it but the output is always `-1`. So the date I get is `2023-03-09`.

I researched for some hours and tried different things but this is the closest I can get. Does anyone have an idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Your question is unclear. When you say " and the function is called it mutates it but the output is always -1" what exactly is set to `-1`? It's very important to note the position of your console log ` console.log(weekDay);` will *always* show the old value because state does not change immediately. Please seehttps://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value. Console log it outside of the `handleDateChange` (in the main body of the component).

Comment: Well the date you mentioned is local time with timezone GMT+0100 when converting to ISO string that becomes 2021-02-09T23:00:00Z. Z is the same as timezone GMT+0000. It's the hour difference that you have between Germany and England.

Comment: He's cutting off the timezone with that slice (which is a very haphazard thing to do, but still). It's a good point though could definitely be related. But it could also be because his log is in the wrong place, he's always logging the previous value without realising it. Common beginner error to forget that `weekDay` will *not* set immediately and will not show the new value in the same event loop. He needs to log it outside of that method so it is captured once react has flushed it and rerenders.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. With -1 I mean I will receive the day I clicked -1. So if I click day 08 I get 07 and if I click 23 I get 22.. you know what I mean? It is not the old value, it is the day I choose - 1.

Comment: In that case @retakenroots is right. If you remove the timezone like this, probably the library (react-calendar) is then parsing it, but now against UTC which is the default, which would offset it by 1 hour, which pushes it into the previous day. Why do you strip the timezone?

Comment: https://linuxhint.com/format-date-as-yyyy-mm-dd-in-javascript/ for a possible solution

Comment: Why are you using `slice()`? If you want a specific date format, use a date formatting library? Or even [Date.toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a yyyy-mm-dd formatted date, don't try to guess where in the string you need to slice. Just use a date formatter. And that includes even using the the built-in [`date.toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString):

```js
console.log(
  (new Date()).toLocaleDateString('de-DE', {
    year: `numeric`,
    month: `2-digit`,
    day: `2-digit`
  }).split(/\D/).reverse().join(`-`)
);
```

Which formats the date as "things with a non-numeric separator" so we split it, reverse the array, and join it back up with `-` so that it's `yyyy-mm-dd`.

And if you *just* need the weekday, then you don't even need that: just ask for it. Date has both "day of the week" and "day of the month" built right into it.

```js
    console.log(`The day of the week for ${new Date()} is ${new Date().getDay()}`);
    console.log(`The day of the month for ${new Date()} is ${new Date().getDate()}`);
```

Comment: I tried a solution like this but It did not work.. I always git yyyy-dd-mm. Maybe I did something wrong.. thank you!

Comment: Remember to upvote useful answers, and accept the answer that solved your problem.

Comment: *toLocaleString* is not a good idea where reliable formatting is required.

Comment: Rob's correct, so don't ignore that "use a date formatter", that's the _first_ thing to try. Using built-in locale formatting is a fallback for when  you know that's safe.